# How come when i click the button my heading doesnt change?

Tags: javascript, events

I know this should be fairly easy, and for some odd reason of all functions work except for this one. I don't see anything I could've possibly done wrong to prevent the onClick event to change the header to blue. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the jfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/CheckLife/680dvv5j/13/

```css
#change {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="change">NBA Legends</h1>
<button onclick="changedColor()">About</button>
<script>
  document.getElementById('change').onclick = changeColor;

  function changeColor() {
    document.body.style.color = "blue";
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: in your html you have changedColor instead changeColor (note the ed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply the style to body, it will be `overriden` because the `element` has it's own style.

So , add the style to the element.

change `document.body.style.color` to `document.getElementById('change').style.color`

See below

```js
document.getElementById('change').onclick = changeColor;

function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById('change').style.color = "#00f";
  return false;
}
```

```css
#change {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="change">NBA Legends</h1>

<button onclick="changeColor()">About</button>
```

Comment: @SagarV - <button onclick="changedColor()">About</button> must be <button onclick="changeColor()">About</button>

Comment: it is ok but see the line _document.getElementById('change').onclick = changeColor;_ in question. It too not working. @Komal

Comment: that was due to <button onclick="changedColor()">About</button> where function name and call was different before edited . thts ok now @SagarV

Comment: ? @Komal ok so i removed the letter "d" and its still not working

Comment: Check this answer. Read the information in the first line. If it helped you , consider +1 and mark it as answer. Try running the snippet. @CheckLife

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo is

```
<button onclick="changeColor()">About</button>
```

instead of

```
<button onclick="changedColor()">About</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `button` onclick Function name `changedColor` to `changeColor`.

```js
  document.getElementById('change').onclick = changeColor;   

  function changeColor() {
      var element = document.getElementById('change')
      element.style.color = "blue";
      return false;
  }
```

```css
#change {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="change">NBA Legends</h1>

<button onclick="changeColor()">About</button>
```